# "TO_DATE" function doesn't change format

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, pg

I have SQL query in my rails application which is as follows

```
  sql = "SELECT id,email,first_name,last_name,street_name,street_number,postal_code,city,region,country,to_date(cast(birth_date as TEXT), 'YYYY'),sex,deceased
           FROM users
           WHERE users.user_role <> 0 AND users.aasm_state = 'complete'
           ORDER BY id"
```

The idea is to display only the year in the field birth_date. But when using the function, only the column name changed, and the date format remained in the form (year, month, day).
I use PG and tried to rewrite this as `to_date(birth_date::TEXT,'YYYY')`, but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want [date function `to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html). This function can be used to format a date or timestamp to a string in a given format:

```
to_char(birth_date , 'YYYY')
```